# Angular, Transloco service is not translating, but inside setTimeout it is translating

Tags: angular, transloco

If I use `this.translocoService.translate(title)` inside `setTimeout`, it is translating. But without `setTimeout`, it says there is no translation.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterStateSnapshot, TitleStrategy } from '@angular/router';
import { TranslocoService } from '@ngneat/transloco';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class CustomTitleStrategyService extends TitleStrategy {
  override updateTitle(snapshot: RouterStateSnapshot): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const title = this.buildTitle(snapshot);
      const translation = this.translocoService.translate(title);
      this.title.setTitle(translation);
    }, 500);
  }

  constructor(
    private title: Title,
    private translocoService: TranslocoService,
  ) {
    super();
  }
}
```

Is there a way to remove setTimeout? because to me it looks like not proper solution

Comment: Sorry, I can not do that. Basically here, .json files are not loading before this this.translocoService.translate(title) is called, thus I use setTimeout, to load .json files before .translate(title). Is there a way to remove setTimeout? so that .json files are loaded before .translate(title)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of relying on fixed amount of time that your app takes to load translation files, you can use `selectTranslate`, which returns observable, to translate the key when the translation is available.

`selectTransalate` method of `TranslateService` returns an observable that when subscribed loads the translation file and emits the translation of the given key.

[source](https://ngneat.github.io/transloco/docs/translation-api)

You can use it in that way:

```
this.translocoService.selectTranslate(title).subscribe(translatedTitle => {
   this.title.setTitle(translatedTitle);
});
```

In order to prevent some jiggle behavior when changing title many times, I'd suggest something like this:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class CustomTitleStrategyService extends TitleStrategy {
  private readonly _title$ = new Subject<string>('');

  override updateTitle(snapshot: RouterStateSnapshot): void {
    this._title$.next(this.buildTitle(snapshot));
  }

  constructor(
    private title: Title,
    private translocoService: TranslocoService,
  ) {
    super();
    this._title$.pipe(
      takeUntilDestroyed(), 
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap(title => this.translocoService.selectTranslate(title))
    ).subscribe(translatedTitle => {
      this.title.setTitle(translatedTitle);
    });
  }
}
```